# how to create site maps from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

An MySQL database contain around 1 million information about domain names. how do I create an xml site map from the said database with PHP 10000 domain names in it.and the xml file should be given a sequent name for example `sitemap1.xml,sitemap2.xml` etc.

Comment: Too broad. What exactly is your question about? Querying the database? Generating the XML?

Comment: yes generating XML files

Comment: What part of the process is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write XML and save it using `file_put_contents()`.
So just loop through all your results and split each file at 10.000 items.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOMDocument. You can use it like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$r = $doc->createElement( "employees" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );

foreach( $employees as $employee )
{
  $b = $doc->createElement( "employee" );

  $name = $doc->createElement( "name" );
  $name->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $employee['name'] )
  );
  $b->appendChild( $name );
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
$doc->save("write.xml")
```